# Android ImageView Circle Placement In RelativeLayout

Tags: android, imageview, android-relativelayout

[image: relative layout]

How to above sequence in RelativeLayout

Comment: i've found a great implementation, but can't get the code: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMbP8-zC-K0

Comment: @Smile2Life did you found any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this library to create circular layout: https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/CircleLayout

Simple code (Using the library) :

```
 <ru.biovamp.widget.CircleLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@android:color/white"
  app:angleOffset="90.0"
  app:layoutMode="pie"
  app:divider="#112233"
  app:innerRadius="40dp"
  app:innerCircle="#119922"
  app:dividerWidth="10dp"
  >

 <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="one"
      android:id="@+id/w"

  />
 <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="two"
      android:id="@+id/w1"
  />
 <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="three"
      android:id="@+id/w2"
  />
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="four"
      android:id="@+id/w3"
  />
       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="five"
      android:id="@+id/w4"
  />

 </ru.biovamp.widget.CircleLayout>
```

NB: you can any Views type (txtviews, buttons, imageviews..)

i was using Samsung [tuto](http://developer.samsung.com/android/samples-4) but link dead, [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer--mobile-8868) another tuto inspired from samsung.

Comment: push up button if you can and my answer is helpful